# How do I import/export menus?

Tags: navigation, 9, importing-exporting, multi-sites

I want to import/export all menus of site1 in into site2. Currently I am using the **entitysync** module to synchronize the content between two sites. I can see there is an option for "Custom Menu Links" but it will import/export only the main navigation items only.

I want to import/export:

**Structure -> Menus**

1. Administration
2. Footer
3. Main Navigation
4. Tools
5. User Account Menu

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Don't the menus point at nodes that won't exist in this site? Anyway, use the Migrate module to migrate data.

Comment: I am using same drupal version , in this case i can't use migrate module

Comment: Yes, you could.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Structure Sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/structure_sync) module:

> Some websites might contain elements that are considered content by the Drupal CMS while they might not only be used as content. For example custom blocks might be used for a footer that is shared between all environments. Structure sync tries to give you a tool to get around this issue by allowing you to **synchronize taxonomy terms, menu links and custom blocks** through the configuration.

Comment: Its between two drupal sites , how can i use structure sync module here??